# SAXReader returns premature end of file

Tags: java, web-services

I have this code which takes an XML file from a URL which is passed through HttpServletRequest request. I have checked the request and inStream's value which are not null/empty. But I get an error "Error on line -1 of document  : Premature end of file. Nested exception: Premature end of file." 
The request and inStream values are shown as 
org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@34a7fc0
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@100917f0
respectively.
The following is the code

```
private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response, VariablesSecureApp vars) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        System.out.println(request);
        InputStream inStream = request.getInputStream();
        System.out.println(inStream);
        SAXReader sax = new SAXReader();
        Document doc = sax.read(inStream);
        System.out.println(doc);
        Element rootElement = (Element) doc.getRootElement();
        if (!rootElement.getName().equals("ob")){
            throw new  OBException("The root element of the xml document should be: Ob but it is " + rootElement.getName());
        }
        //createSalesOrder(doc,response,request);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(inStream);` ?!?

Comment: just to check inStream's value. Whether is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because the XML file you are reading is not properly formed.

That can mean a missing end tag, or even when an end of file character is not found.

Comment: What would these characters look like?